# tiny_obj_loader to Direct3D Vertex Buffer and Index Buffer Arrays

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2015, directx

Im getting an error during `pSwapChain->Present()` that I cannot debug.

Im utilizing DXUT examples and building an OBJ loader. For this I'm copying functionality from `SDKmesh` class and using `tiny_obj_loader` class to load the obj file.

The error I'm getting is

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FF89DC288A8 (nvwgf2umx.dll) in test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.
```

My test code for importing obj is below.

I do realize I'm stupidly casting tiny_obj_loader structures into ID3D11Buffers. But I would hope that tiny_obj_loader at least attempts to replicate those buffer structures. Or do I need a better obj import library? Can anyone recommend one that is compatible with DirectX?

```
bool DXUTModel::LoadOBJ(std::string object_file)
{
    IModel::LoadOBJ(object_file);

    int num_vertices = attrib.vertices.size();
    int num_indices = shapes[0].mesh.indices.size();

    g_Mesh11.m_ppVertices = (BYTE**)&attrib.vertices;
    g_Mesh11.m_ppIndices = (BYTE**)&shapes[0].mesh.indices;

    g_Mesh11.m_pMaterialArray = new SDKMESH_MATERIAL;
    std::wstring strPath = L"Media\\Base_skin.dds";
    if (FAILED(DXUTGetGlobalResourceCache().CreateTextureFromFile(dxCtr->m_pDevice, dxCtr->m_pImmediateContext, strPath.c_str(), &g_Mesh11.m_pMaterialArray->pDiffuseRV11,true)))
        g_Mesh11.m_pMaterialArray->pDiffuseRV11 = (ID3D11ShaderResourceView*)ERROR_RESOURCE_VALUE;

    //Set Vertex Buffer Array
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray = new SDKMESH_MESH;
    g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_VERTEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0] = 0;
    g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].pVB11 = (ID3D11Buffer*)&attrib.vertices;
    g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].StrideBytes = 32;

    //Set Index Buffer array
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer = 0;
    g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_INDEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
    g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].IndexType = IT_16BIT;
    g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].pIB11 = (ID3D11Buffer*)&shapes[0].mesh.indices;

    //Set subset
    SDKMESH_SUBSET v_subset;
    v_subset.MaterialID = 0;
    v_subset.PrimitiveType = PT_TRIANGLE_LIST;
    v_subset.IndexCount = shapes[0].mesh.indices.size();
    v_subset.VertexCount = attrib.vertices.size();
    v_subset.VertexStart = 0;
    v_subset.IndexStart = 0;
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets = new UINT;
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0] = 0;
    g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].NumSubsets = 1;
    g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray = new SDKMESH_SUBSET;
    g_Mesh11.m_pSubsetArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].pSubsets[0]] = v_subset;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what `tiny_obj_loader` does, but all those random casts are just straight shots in the leg. Judging from variables names you will need to create DirectX buffers for mesh vertex and indexes obtained from that library using `ID3D11Device::CreateBuffer`. You also need to make sure that loaded vertexes are compatible with the shader you are using.

Comment: If you are asking for recommendations of libraries, this question is off-topic. If you are looking for help with your issue, it may not be. Probably best to drop those inquiries for better/other libraries to make room for information detailing your issue (like a call stack).

Comment: Thanks, I just now realized I cant cast CPU memory to GPU buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to have fixed the initial error replacing:

```
//g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].pVB11 = (ID3D11Buffer*)&attrib.vertices;
//g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].pIB11 = (ID3D11Buffer*)&shapes[0].mesh.indices;
```

with:

```
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
bufferDesc.ByteWidth = (UINT)(attrib.vertices.size()*4);
bufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
InitData.pSysMem = &attrib.vertices[0];
dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &InitData, &g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].pVB11);
g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].StrideBytes = 32;
g_Mesh11.m_pVertexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].VertexBuffers[0]].SizeBytes = attrib.vertices.size() * 4;

//Set Index Buffer array
g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer = 0;
g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray = new SDKMESH_INDEX_BUFFER_HEADER;
g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].IndexType = IT_16BIT;
D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc2;
bufferDesc2.ByteWidth = (UINT)(shapes[0].mesh.indices.size());
bufferDesc2.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
bufferDesc2.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
bufferDesc2.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
bufferDesc2.MiscFlags = 0;
D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData2;
InitData2.pSysMem = &shapes[0].mesh.indices[0];
dxCtr->m_pDevice->CreateBuffer(&bufferDesc, &InitData2, &g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].pIB11);
g_Mesh11.m_pIndexBufferArray[g_Mesh11.m_pMeshArray[0].IndexBuffer].SizeBytes = shapes[0].mesh.indices.size();
```

It's drawing something, it's not pretty but it has a texture. Will post code when I get it working correctly